# Office 365 Unified APIs: Files respond with 401

Tags: office365, office365api

When querying files using "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/files" the following response is returned:

HTTP 401 {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}

1. Other operations succeed (ex: /beta/groups, /beta/me ) and the authentication process (using access tokens) seems o.k.
2. The app has all 25 Unified API permissions (inc files read/write) in Azure | ActiveDirectory | Apps
3. Tried with different users / admin users.
4. [API Sandbox](https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/%20API%20Sanbox) has a demo for the files api (/beta/me/files)

Comment: Do you see Files.Read or Files.ReadWrite in the scp claim if you go to http://jwt.calebb.net/ and decode the JWT access token?

Comment: Yes. scp: "AllSites.Read Files.Read full_access_as_user Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Send MyFiles.Read openid User.Read",

Comment: Hi Dekel, Can you try using the Graph Explorer Web App to make your query? https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/

Let us know if you are still running into issues here. Thanks, Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: Repro using GraphExplorer - same error as above.